# WPF - Effects of "Center" vertical alignment on negative margins

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Attempting to animate a control by modifying its margins, I realized that I might not fully understand the effects of the different alignment options on negative margins. To better explain my question, I created an example containing two TextBlock controls each surrounded by a Border.

As shown below, I attempt to give the first TextBlock `_TextBlock1` (blue) - which has a vertical alignment of `Top` - a top margin of -20 so that its bottom edge will sit immediately on top of its border `_Border1`. This produces the desired result. I then attempt to achieve the same effect on TextBlock `_TextBlock2` (orange), which is identical to `_TextBlock1` except for its vertical alignment of `Center`. Since this TextBlock is centered vertically, I apply a top margin of -40, which from my understanding should produce the same result (20 pixels to move its top edge to the top edge of the border `_Border2` and another 20 pixels to bring it fully above the border).

As shown on the image below - taken from the designer view in Visual Studio - I seem to be missing something about how the margins affect the placement of these controls given their vertical alignment type. **Could somebody explain to me how I should be interpreting the interaction between margins and alignment types (as related to this example)? Also, how can I modify the margins on `_TextBlock2` to produce the same results as `_TextBlock1`?**

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border
            x:Name="_Border1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">

            <TextBlock
                Margin="0 -20 0 0"
                x:Name="_TextBlock1"
                Background="DodgerBlue"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Height="20"/>
        </Border>

        <Border
            x:Name="_Border2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">

            <TextBlock
                Margin="0 -40 0 0"
                x:Name="_TextBlock2"
                Background="Orange"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Height="20"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you considered putting them in a Canvas and animating Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top instead?

Comment: Not really. You mean wrapping each TextBlock in its own Canvas and then just animating its placement? Is there a particular reason why you suggest this? I'm curious because that hadn't even crossed my mind.

Comment: I suggest it because that's how you do arbitrary control placement in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Margins do not ‘move’ an element.  Margins effectively grow or shrink the size of an element’s layout rectangle, which is provided by its parent.  Alignment controls how an element positions itself *within* its layout rectangle.

Initially, the orange block has its parent’s entire area available for positioning, so its layout rectangle starts with a height of `60`.   Normally, adding (positive) margins *shrinks* the portion of the layout rectangle available to position an element.  But a top margin of `-40` effectively *grows* the orange block’s layout rectangle so it has a height of `60 - (-40) = 100`.  Let’s define the top-left corner of our effective layout rectangle as being `(0, 0)`.  Relative to this, the parent border’s top-left corner is `(0, 40)`.

The orange block has a height of `20`, and it has `100` units of vertical space in which to center itself.  `(100 - 20) / 2 = 40`, so the block gets `40` units of vertical space above it and below it.  This puts the orange block’s top-left corner at `(0, 40)`, right along with its parent.

[image: Layout Diagram]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had already read the documentation regarding margins, padding, and alignment but your explanation made all of that really click.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your _TextBlock2 as below to obtain required behaviour:

```
<TextBlock
                Margin="0 -80 0 0"
                x:Name="_TextBlock2"
                Background="Orange"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Height="20"/>
```

To have a better understanding regarding margins and padding go [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)